# Python Regex match a mac address from the end?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following re to extract MAC address:

```
re.sub( r'(\S{2,2})(?!$)\s*', r'\1:', '0x0000000000aa bb ccdd ee ff' )
```

However, this gave me `0x:00:00:00:00:00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff`.

How do I modify this regex to stop after matching the first 6 pairs starting from the end, so that I get `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff`?

Note: the string has whitespace in between which is to be ignored. Only the last 12 characters are needed.

**Edit1:** `re.findall( r'(\S{2})\s*(\S{2})\s*(\S{2})\s*(\S{2})\s*(\S{2})\s*(\S{2})\s*$',a)` finds the last 6 pairs in the string. I still don't know how to compress this regex. Again this still depends on the fact that the strings are in pairs.

Ideally the regex should take the last 12 valid `\S` characters starting from the end and string them with `:`

**Edit2:** Inspired by @Mariano answer which works great but depends on the fact that that last 12 characters must start with a pair I came up with the following solution. It is kludgy but still seems to work for all inputs.

```
string = '0x0000000000a abb ccddeeff'
':'.join( ''.join( i ) for i in re.findall( '(\S)\s*(\S)(?!(?:\s*\S\s*{11})',' string) )
'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'
```

**Edit3:** @Mariano has updated his answer which now works for all inputs

Comment: The dollar sign, `$`, represents the end of line. Use that to express that after 6 matches you want the line to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for the last 12 characters, ignoring whitespace.

**Code:**

```
import re

text = "0x0000000000aa bb ccdd ee ff"

result = re.sub( r'.*?(?!(?:\s*\S){13})(\S)\s*(\S)', r':\1\2', text)[1:]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/DGUA19573)

---

**Regex breakdown:**

The expression used in this code uses `re.sub()` to replace the following in the subject text:

```
.*?                 # consume the subject text as few as possible
(?!(?:\s*\S){13})   # CONDITION: Can't be followed by 13 chars
                    #  so it can only start matching when there are 12 to $
(\S)\s*(\S)         # Capture a char in group 1, next char in group 2
                    #
  # The match is replaced with :\1\2
  # For this example, re.sub() returns ":aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff"
  # We'll then apply [1:] to the returned value to discard the leading ":"
```

Comment: This works ! can you add a brief explanation on what the re does ?

Comment: just noticed that we are still dependent on the fact that the 12,11 string from the end must be in pairs.

Comment: `':'.join( ''.join( i ) for i in re.findall( '(\S)\s*(\S)(?!(?:\s*\S\s*){11})','0x0000000000aabb ccddeeff') )` seems to work for any input

Comment: Updated answer to meet all requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.finditer` to find all the pairs then join the result :

```
>>> my_string='0x0000000000aa bb ccdd ee ff'
>>> ':'.join([i.group() for i in re.finditer( r'([a-z])\1+',my_string )])
'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'
```

Comment: only the last 12 characters are to be matched. This will match any [a-z] pairs eg: `0x0000000000zzaa bb ccdd ee ff` the `zz` should be ignored

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '0x0000000000aa bb ccdd ee ff'
>>> re.sub(r'(?!^)\s*(?=(?:\s*[a-z]{2})+$)', ':', re.sub(r'.*?((?:\s*[a-z]){12})\s*$', r'\1', s ))
'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'
>>> s = '???767aa bb ccdd ee ff'
>>> re.sub(r'(?!^)\s*(?=(?:\s*[a-z]{2})+$)', ':', re.sub(r'.*?((?:\s*[a-z]){12})\s*$', r'\1', s ))
'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'
>>> s = '???767aa bb ccdd eeff    '
>>> re.sub(r'(?!^)\s*(?=(?:\s*[a-z]{2})+$)', ':', re.sub(r'.*?((?:\s*[a-z]){12})\s*$', r'\1', s ))
'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but do you really need a regular expression? If your format is fixed, this should also work:

```
>>> s = '0x0000000000aa bb ccdd ee ff'
>>> ':'.join([s[-16:-8].replace(' ', ':'), s[-8:].replace(' ', ':')])
'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'
```